# Writing data to an excel template with many formula and styles and color takes too much time

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm trying to write data to excel template which contains many formula and style. If i had formula/formatting copied to 100 rows*601 cells, excel downloads with in second after writing data but as soon as i stretch it to say 3000 rows*601 cells and even if i write it to 70 rows,it takes forever and hangs down the server. This happens because workbook.write(outputstream) takes too much time.
If i increase heap size it works for 1500 rows which takes around 15 to 20 sec to download.

I have tried SXSSFWorkbook, but this doesn't allow me to write in existing rows. To avoid this i keep one XSSFWorkbook to read data and SXSSFWorkbook to write, the problem is i was unable to get colors and style from my actual template to other, and data also get messed up.

This works but i have to increase heap size with increase in number of rows, i have tested it for 1500 rows resultant file size is 3.5 MB.

```
private Workbook dumpDataToMaster(List<Map<String, Object>> excelData,Map<String, String> fileType) throws IOException {
        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/excel_templates/"+fileType.get("file")));

        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(fileType.get("sheetName"));
        Iterator<Cell> headerItr = sheet.getRow(3).iterator();
        List<String> headers = new ArrayList<>();



        while(headerItr.hasNext()) {
            headers.add(headerItr.next().getStringCellValue());
        }

        int headersSize = headers.size();
        int excelDataSize = excelData.size();

        IntStream.range(0,excelDataSize).forEach(eIndex->{
            Row dataRow = sheet.getRow(eIndex+4);
            IntStream.range(0,headersSize).forEach(index->{

                Object value = excelData.get(eIndex).get(headers.get(index));
                if(value != null) {
                    if (value instanceof String) {
                        dataRow.getCell(index).setCellValue((String)value);
                    } else if(value instanceof Number) {
                        dataRow.getCell(index).setCellValue(((Number)value).doubleValue());
                    } else if(value instanceof Date) {
                        dataRow.getCell(index).setCellValue((Date)value);
                    }
                }
            });
        });


        sheet.getRow(1).getCell(1).setCellValue(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        workbook.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);
        return workbook;
    }
```

Controller for above method looks like this

```
public void downloadDDTemplate(@RequestParam String values, @OrgModelAttribute("sessionElements") SessionElements sessionElements, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        OrderTemplateType orderTemplateType = objectMapper.readValue(values, OrderTemplateType.class);
        response.setHeader(Constant.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,
                "attachment; filename=\"" +  orderTemplateType.getDisplay()+" - Template - "
                        + DateTimeFormatConfiguration.getFileNameDateFormat().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime())
                        + ".xlsx\"");
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
        orderMasterService.downloadDDTemplate(orderTemplateType).write(response.getOutputStream());
        response.flushBuffer();
    }
```

second method i have tried is

```
private Workbook dumpDataToMaster(List<Map<String, Object>> excelData,Map<String, String> fileType, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {
        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/excel_templates/"+fileType.get("file")));

        XSSFWorkbook readWb = new XSSFWorkbook(workbook);
        Sheet readSheet = readWb.getSheet(fileType.get("sheetName"));
        //inputStream.close();

        SXSSFWorkbook writeWb = new SXSSFWorkbook(); 
        writeWb.setCompressTempFiles(true);
        SXSSFSheet writeSheet = writeWb.createSheet(fileType.get("sheetName"));//(SXSSFSheet) wb.getSheet(fileType.get("sheetName"));
        writeSheet.setRandomAccessWindowSize(1600);
        Iterator<Cell> headerItr = readSheet.getRow(3).iterator();
        List<String> headers = new ArrayList<>();

        CellStyle dateStyle = writeWb.createCellStyle();
        CreationHelper createHelper = writeWb.getCreationHelper();
        dateStyle.setDataFormat(
            createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("dd-mm-yyyy"));


        while(headerItr.hasNext()) {
            String value = headerItr.next().getStringCellValue();
            headers.add(value);
            Row auxWriteRow = writeSheet.createRow(3);
            Cell auxWriteCell = auxWriteRow.createCell(headers.size()-1);
            auxWriteCell.setCellValue(value);
        }

        int headersSize = headers.size();
        int excelDataSize = excelData.size();

        IntStream.range(0,excelDataSize).forEach(eIndex->{
            Row dataRow = readSheet.getRow(eIndex+4);
            Row writeRow = writeSheet.createRow(eIndex+4);
            IntStream.range(0,headersSize).forEach(index->{

                Cell writeCell = writeRow.createCell(index);
                Cell readCell = dataRow.getCell(index);
                Object value = excelData.get(eIndex).get(headers.get(index));
                if(readCell != null && CellType.FORMULA.equals(readCell.getCellType())) {
                    writeCell.setCellFormula(readCell.getCellFormula());
                }
                writeCell.getCellStyle();
                if(value != null) {
                    if (value instanceof String) {
                        XSSFCellStyle newCellStyle = (XSSFCellStyle) writeCell.getSheet().getWorkbook().createCellStyle();     
                        writeCell.setCellStyle(copyCellStyle((XSSFCell)readCell, newCellStyle)); 
                        writeCell.setCellType(readCell.getCellType());
                        writeCell.setCellValue((String)value);
                    } else if(value instanceof Number) {
                        XSSFCellStyle newCellStyle = (XSSFCellStyle) writeCell.getSheet().getWorkbook().createCellStyle();     
                        writeCell.setCellStyle(copyCellStyle((XSSFCell)readCell, newCellStyle)); 
                        writeCell.setCellStyle(readCell.getCellStyle()); 
                        writeCell.setCellType(readCell.getCellType());
                        writeCell.setCellValue(((Number)value).doubleValue());
                    } else if(value instanceof Date) {
                        writeCell.setCellStyle(dateStyle); 
                        writeCell.setCellType(readCell.getCellType());
                        writeCell.setCellValue((Date)value);
                    }
                }
            });
        });

        int lastRow = sheet.getLastRowNum();

        for (int eIndex=0; eIndex<=lastRow; eIndex++) {
            Row dataRow = sheet.getRow(eIndex+excelDataSize+4);
            if(dataRow == null)
                break;
            sheet.removeRow(dataRow);
        }
        Cell cell = writeSheet.createRow(1).createCell(1);
        cell.setCellStyle(dateStyle);
        cell.setCellValue(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(workbook);
        writeWb.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);
        writeWb.write(response.getOutputStream());
        writeWb.close();
        readWb.close();
        return writeWb;
    }
```

Is there any way to achieve this faster,with less memory footprint on consumption.

Comment: How big is your heap? Apache poi is really bad with memory management. The least memory expensive solution would be to write to the XML files directly, but thats most probably overkill

Comment: For 1500 rows i have allocated 4gb.

Comment: As your final file size should be at max 8MB, are you sure it stops on the `writeWb.write(response.getOutputStream())`? Does the writing etc work if you execute it locally?

Comment: No sometimes i  gc out of memory exception and when i go to task manager ram and cpu get's stuck at 100% usage and server breaks down or gets really slow. So i want to know that is there any efficient way to do this because row in my case can be more than 10,000.

Comment: [Check point 14](https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html) and execute [the performance test](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/ss/examples/SSPerformanceTest.java). You can then alter rows and columns to match your setup and see if it still runs

Comment: I seriously think that either your environment is very bad, or your code is very poorly written. I ran the test mentioned above on my PC and it finished easily within less than 30 seconds. You should definitly not keep 2 files open at the same time. Just write to the `XSSFWorkbook` and remove the `SXSSFWorkbook`

Comment: Yes, right now i am using the first version of code, if i write it to empty excel file  it downloads within seconds but problem is if i write it to a file which has lots of style,colors and formula then writing excel file to output stream takes too much time.Every thing above the write method takes minimal time. I think you tried to write on a excel file with no or minimal formula and styles.

Comment: Thats true, yet I just recently worked on templates with a good amount of forumals and styles. Yes it is fairly slow to write, but without knowing more about the template itself, its hard/impossible to tell what causes the issue

Comment: I will try to provide you the excel, i have to ask my manager :D

Comment: No need to provide it, as we can't reproduce the issue anyways. Have you run the performance test now? What parameters did you use? what was the result?